# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I am not sure if this is early or not , but I believe it is a good one to ask before the public beta.  I got this from [the seven essential question for every meta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

***How do we promote our site?***

*This is rapidly becoming a hot issue across the entire network: how to promote your site and how to reach out to the experts and peers in your industry. We can come up with budgets and promotions but the means and ideas about how to reach your target audience HAS TO come from you and your community. Has to. Has to, has to, has to! We simply are not experts in your field. We don’t have the the connections nor the experience you bring to the table. You are both our evangelist and our ambassador — and sharing links to great questions and answers is the best way to start*

Comment: I expected this question to come up. at least wait till we get out of private beta!

Comment: The reason I asked this question while we were still in privet beta is that if we are ready and stuff, than when we get to public beta things will move smoothly along.

Comment: Related: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/190/most-interesting-questions-answers

Answer (score 8):

**1. Invite People**

The simplest way to promote this site is to invite experts in the field to join this network. I have personally sent invitation to some prominent scholars including Yousaf Estes. We need experts here. We simply do not have enough knowledge because most of us are primarily programmers.

**2. Visit often**

Do not just take a long break from the site. We need more views.

**3. Ask questions**

If you do not ask question, there is no purpose of this site. There are huge number of questions out there. We need to ask those question. Anything will help.

It is crucial that we take it seriously. Come up with any questions? Gather questions from friends? Think about the problem we face today and ask questions about it? Once we have more quality question, experts will be more willing to join and answer the questions.

An easy tip is just invite your friends and people you know who have questions. It is better for them and it is better for you.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

## Share, Share, Share!

- **Post questions and answers to Reddit, Twitter, Facebook, etc.** If the question is popular, it'll blow up with views. This can lead users to the site.
- **Share at your local Mosque.** Find your Imam and ask him to make an announcement about the site. It can help this community, and the Mosque's community.
- **Make posts more searchable.** Titles should be about what the question is about. This will help Googlers who are looking for answers find our site.
- **Tell your friends.**

There are also ways to promote the site for those who are already using the site.

- Eventually, we can start a **contest**.
- We can have a **blog**.

If we do the above, this site can be one of the biggest communities on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Note that contests and blogs are for  graduated sites only, IIRC.

Comment: @Manishearth I'm not sure about contests, but blogs are definitely allowed while in Beta. Look at Christianity.SE.

Comment: Sorry, forgot. Not "graduated sites", I mean more of "sites which have been around for a while and have a stable userbase". I doubt they will make a contest for you _now_ (blog may be easier to get), but you ought to keep these ideas in mind for later

Comment: @Manishearth Of course not ([Programmer.SE] just got there blog and contest recently), but I am looking forward to it :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are various steps to go about it

- **By word of mouth** - You can obviously tell your friends, co workers, relatives etc about this this thing. Also check out this [Elevator pitch](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57/whats-the-elevator-pitch-for-our-site) thingy
- **Make an advertisement** - This is being followed on [Chem.SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/134/124) and [Math.SE](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/what-would-be-a-good-community-promotion-ad) & if we are lucky we can get our add posted  on some other SE site like [Physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/980). Another thing you can do is take a print and post in around your locality, outside your local mosque etc.
- **Blather about it on your blog** - If you have a blog (not necessarily a successful one) just promote it in any way you seem fit.
- **Make a Facebook page** - Make a Facebook page, act like a true troll and post the link to that page all over Facebook (well there are many Islamic pages on FB, you can post there if you want.) But be sensible and make only one page. Please discuss this in chat before making a page. (Also see [Ways to Promote Your Facebook Fan Page](http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/20-ways-to-promote-your-facebook-fan-page/))
- **Twitter** - SE sites have a way to automatically post to twitter (i don't know how). Maybe someone can get this working. Tweet Tweet.
- **A Youtube video** - This is something new. Well i thing there are a few programmers/ developers on this site. You could make a simple video about advantages of such a site with its link would be helpful.
- **Post about it on other forums** - Are you active on some other forum? Then this is for you!!! Just post its link with a short description.
- **Spread a word of it  on whatever social networking site you are on** - Whether you are on Google+, Fb, Twitter, HiFive, Myspace etc make it a point to mention about it.

  [image]
  You should find this on the main page.
- ...

Answer (score 2):

> Pretty much copied from http://meta.libraries.stackexchange.com/a/109
>
> Related questions on other new sites: [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/how-do-we-promote-our-shiny-new-site/), [Libraries](http://meta.libraries.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-do-we-spread-the-word-about-our-awesome-site), [Chess](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/what-avenues-of-site-promotion-do-we-have-available/) , [WindowsPhone](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-do-we-promote-this-site) (these are some of our newer sites, you can probably find the [site-promotion](/questions/tagged/site-promotion) questions on the older ones if you want. Or use [this filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/49021/meta-site-promotion) I just created)

Few things you can do (some stuff taken from my post [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/what-can-i-do-for-this-site)):

- Create a community promotion ad and post on a graduated site.   [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/what-would-be-a-good-community-promotion-ad) and [chem.SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/140/22) have done so on Physics.
- Create an A4(or whatever) poster for your users to print out and stick somewhere. [We did that on chem](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/134/22)
- Write an awesome blog post, like [this one by a TW mod](http://www.thickbook.com/2012/02/dear-stackexchange-will-you-be-my-valentine/)
- Encourage colleagues/classmates/friends(who would be interested) to join. Tell them how awesome we are!
- Try to get more experts engaged. Remember, the more experts you have, the better the site is (we don't want to degrade into Yahoo! Answers)
- Retweet the upvoted questions posted by [@StackIslam](http://twitter.com/#!/StackIslam), your friendly neighborhood bot. This spreads the word about the site pretty easily.