# How should we deal with "half-answers"?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I would like to reiterate a point I brought up to a semi-related question [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/713):

> …I have seen many cases of users (often in chat,
>   occasionally in comments) giving fully detailed — and valid — answers
>   to extant questions, but refraining from actually writing a proper
>   answer just because they don't have the references available.

This is not necessarily limited to answers that lack references; I have seen similar behaviour for answers that answer *most* (but not all) of the question itself.

The problem is, neither chat nor comments are designed for answers — that's what the *answer* field is for — and answers placed therein are unnecessarily crippled.  They are harder to *search*, nigh-impossible to *edit*, cannot be properly *voted on*, and even if they could be they are not *sorted*.  And, right or wrong, they have *zero effect* on the posters reputation.  They are, quite frankly, horrible places to put answers.

How, then, *should* we be dealing with these "half-answers"; those answers which may still be useful — not to mention correct — but lack enough "meat" (either in the opinion of the site's community, or the poster himself) to stand alone as a proper answer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe they still have a place on this site.  For if it is the first answer to the question, and still answers it but not fully they should be commented on.  I don't believe they should be eligible for down-voting because they still answer the question, as well it is useful.  If it is upvoted then most likely it is upvoted for it's usefulness and quality.  If a question has a number of answers, and someone comes a long and sees that all the answers didn't explain an answer to part of the question correctly or not as good and believes he/she can explain it better for that part of the question, then I believe that this should be allowed.

If a half an answer if given because that is what the user has knowledge in, or doesn't have sufficient knowledge or references to answer the other part, I believe should still be welcome.  For it is still answering the question, only just a part of it.  And the user is putting time into it and that should be appreciated.  Also half answers **may** (this may not be the case the majority of the time) indicate that the questioner is asking a question that may need to be split into two, but again this may most likely be a rare case.

Again, to repeat what I said in the beginning, the answer should be commented on, and if a new user then warmly welcome them first.  This is my opinion, May Allah forgive my short comings, and guide us all.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the text into a community wiki answer may not be a bad idea, as you did. Any user can do this.