# List of 27 "unanswered" questions which are answered in the comments (Mar 2018)

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

Here's a list of questions which are currently considered to be "unanswered" (i.e., they appear on the [unanswered](https://islam.stackexchange.com/unanswered) list), but I consider them answered in the comments.

This is mostly a reference post.

I went through [a data explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/islam/query/831569/unanswered-questions-with-comments) which lists questions with no answers but comments.  I manually checked them for answers in comments (using my own judgement).  These are all the ones I found.  I don't plan to add to this list again.

It'd help reduce our unanswered percentage to get these answered in an answer (with reliable Islamic references added).

Some of these were answered before I had even finished making this list.  Kudos.  **Excellent!  Some of these are getting good answers!!**

1. <s>[As a convert woman married to a Catholic with no legal separation, how can I marry a Muslim man?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29461/17163)</s>

   > If you accepted islam, then from a shariah point of view you would be regarded as divorced after idah by traditional scholars. But you might be legally a bigamist in a non-muslim country! And scholars would recommend to take local laws and costums into account!
2. <s>[If a body part is colored by Hindus in Holi, will it be struck off on judgement day?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30535/17163)</s>

   In the comments, the OP asks for a hadith.

   > Well that sounds to me as a fabrication,a s i never heard a hadith mentioning hindus
3. <s>[Is conversion between Islamic denominations considered apostasy?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30813/17163)</s>

   > I'd qualify this as opinion-based. If you left denomination A to denomination B, while a considers B as non-Mulsims of course your former brothers from denomination A would consider you as an apostate while those of denomination B would consider you a convert/revert. And that depends on denominations and the relation between them...
4. <s>[Do Muslims hold the biography (Sira) of Prophet Muhammad with the same status as the Quran and Hadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31288/17163)</s>  (Closed.)

   > It would be nice if you elaborated your post and clarified what you exactly mean? As there's nothing in Islam that has the same status of the Qur'an. The hadith or sunnah follows and to some extent Sira has a similar way of transmission of both of them, but most earlier historians have an ambivalent reputation.
5. <s>[Immediately after the shahadah, what is the phrase used in the chant, (besides Allahu Akbar)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31429/17163)</s>

   > Salam and welcome to Islam SE. He and before that -apparently- the audiance is saying: "Takbeer"=saying Allahu Akbar.
6. [If I give sadaqah is that recorded for my father, given that he supports me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32968/17163)  (This one is more complicated than I first thought.)

   > Every good deed you do, is automatically recorded for your parents if they are/were muslim and had taught you to do good deeds. Also in this case the money you will give sadaqah is also from him, so he will get reward, you don't need to worry.
7. <s>[Is it true that Allah will not accept any one's excuses after 60 years?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35242/17163)</s>

   > This hadith refers to being excused, not repenting and not being forgiven. In other words, it means those who die of old age (60 years means shayb or grey hair), and die without repenting, will have no excuse in front of Allah, like claiming had they lived longer, they would have repented. Forgiveness is till the soul reaches the throat at the time of one's death.
8. [What is permitted as dowry, besides money, for the bride? (Sunni viewpoint)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35536/17163)

   > Anything which has a value see for example what I've quoted here islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25811/… some scholars even accept it if the husband offers to memorize the Quran or parts of it.
9. <s>[Are random rewards haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35829/17163)</s>

   > As far as I'm aware, gambling in islam is when someone who stands to lose something depending on the outcome of an uncertain event also stands to gain something depending on the outcome of the same uncertain event (I don't remember the concise way it is usually phrased, but this is the gist I think), so a give-away for ordinary customers without their having to pay specifically to take part in the give-away is allowed. I'm pretty sure I saw fatawa to that effect too, but don't have the time to dig them up, so maybe this is enough of a lead.
10. [Preference of interpersonal commandments?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36321/17163)

    > There are some quotes according to which Allah my forgive any sin we may commit, except those we have harmed other people! ... What came to mind is sunnah.com/muslim/45/77 , sunnah.com/bukhari/46/10 and sunnah.com/adab/42/6 ...
11. [Acting upon a Hasan (good) Hadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36620/17163)

    > A hadith hassan is by default a hadith which is sahih but has not the necessary tawatur! So it is a hadith we should follow if it neither contradicts neither the Quran nor any sahih (mutawatir) hadith! Note that in both sahihs books there are around 200 narrations which strictly speaking are even only ahaad so they don't even reach the grade of a hassan hadith!
12. <s>[Should a woman who gives birth and gets divorced shortly afterwards complete her period of waiting (iddat)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36872/17163)</s>

    > If a woman was married and given talaq (divorce) a ' idah is always needed before a new marriage no matter if she was pregnant or not, not able to give birth etc. for each case the quran defines a clear 'idah.
13. <s>[What is the meaning of consort in the following context?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38239/17163)</s>

    > It means having sex, being intimate.
14. <s>[Is it permissible to correct my name to match how it's pronounced in Arabic?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38845/17163)</s>

    > The question might be is it useful or necessary? It is indeed permissible to change names into better one, but the legal part at your place might be the bigger issue and therefore one needs to ask what is the benefit? You could easily ask people to call you the way you like.
15. [Are women in hijab assumed not to be "asking for it" in sexual assault cases?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39104/17163)

    > Unlike western law, there is no concept of *ambiguity of consent*. The intercourse itself is inherently unlawful in Islam in the absence of a provable Nikah, and private consent does not constitute a valid Nikah. The Hadd will be carried out when proof of action is established and the perpetrator is only excused because of lunacy, minority or violent compulsion. So no, the victim will not be asked about her clothing, nor will it be admitted as an excuse or mitigation.
16. <s>[How to greet a group of people in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40814/17163)</s>

    > It depends one greeting for everybody is sufficient if you make yourself heard, else of course greeting each one separately is also fine, and you may gain more rewards.
17. [What does "the moon arose and it was like a piece of plate" mean the moon will look like during Laylat al-Qadr?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40919/17163)

    > In the stated Hadith, the word piece of plate does not mean to be a Full Moon, rather it means to be in the Waning stages. Which means that those were the last days of the month.
18. [What was the exact duration of Hazrat Safiyya (r.a.) idda?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/42706/17163)

    > Her iddah was one menses as she was a captive. I guess i've quoted that in one of my answers.
19. <s>[Can a marriage be valid if the man is a revert whose parents are Muslim and Hindu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43240/17163)</s>

    > The fairh of the parents is irrelevant to any marriage.
20. [What is meant by "increasing disbelief" in Surah Aal 'Imraan verse 90?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43389/17163)

    > As long as you don't die while saying words of disbelieve or being a kafir your repentence might be accepted.
21. <s>[Can I bring my own Quran inside the mosque and read?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/44586/17163)</s>

    > Yes, that is perfectly fine. (But going forward, try to learn Arabic because you lose out on great reward by not reading/reciting the Qur'an in its original language).
22. <s>[Is the night prayer obligatory or desirable?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/45148/17163)</s>

    > It is certainly not obligatory by all madhhabs. There are only five obligatory prayers.
23. [What does the circular (sometimes crescent-like) symbol on top of Islamic Minarets and Domes represent?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/45276/17163)

    > The crescent not having having a religious basis doesn't mean that it isn't part of Muslim culture, albeit adopted from the Turks rather than the Arabs.
24. <s>[Is there a term to describe narrations from Sahaba?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/45692/17163)</s>

    > You are referring to either athar or hadith mawquf. There is no collection of such in one or more books, but it is always possible to find references to them in books of hadiths collection.
25. <s>[Can you enter jannah just by pray juma(friday prayer)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/45846/17163)</s> (Although the kufr part could still use addressing.)

    > All sahaba were in consensus that a person who doesn't pray or pay zakat is not a Muslim. As a Muslim you can't chose whether you pray only jumu'ah or your daily prayers as this would mean you accept some of your duties and deny some (kufr).
26. <s>[Why do we blame Shaitan for bad acts and not ourselves?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46397/17163)</s>

    > Please provide your evidence that we blame the Shaitan and not ourselves in Islam. In fact, it is the disbelievers who blame the Shaitan and not themselves (see 14:22).
27. <s>[What is a langar - it is served?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46502/17163)</s>

    > Langar (Punjabi: ਲੰਗਰ) (kitchen) is the term used in Sikhism for the community kitchen in a Gurdwara where a free meal is served to all the visitors, without distinction of religion, caste, gender, economic status or ethnicity. The free meal is always vegetarian.[1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/unanswered) People sit on the floor, eat together, and the kitchen is maintained and serviced by Sikh community volunteers.[2](http://data.stackexchange.com/islam/query/831569/unanswered-questions-with-comments)

---

See also: [Answers on comment section?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1776/17163)

Meta.SE has a post [Why do some people answer in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4217/351283)